# data entered in fields disappears when file is uploaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this form with a lot of input fields in page including dropdownlist, textboxes and textarea. And at the end of page, I have file uploading field.
The problem is when I entered all the data in the fields and I attached a file at the end, all the data I entered disappears and I need to retype again.

I have this code below. Here I use a Session to hold the data to retain the values entered in fields when uploading a file, but still the data disappears after a file has uploaded.
Can someone help me resolve this? Thank you so much.

CONTROLLER

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        All_Issues all_Issues = new All_Issues();
        ViewBag.StatusID = new SelectList(db.issue_status_ref, "StatusID", "StatusName");
        ViewBag.IncLevelID = new SelectList(db.incident_level_ref, "IncLevelID", "Description");
        ViewBag.DeptID = new SelectList(db.all_department_ref, "department_id", "department_name");
        ViewBag.CatID = new SelectList(db.category_ref, "CatID", "Category");
        ViewBag.NocID = new SelectList(db.nature_of_occurrence_ref, "NocID", "Title");
        ViewBag.UsersID = new SelectList(db.ad_users, "user_id", "display_name");

        if (Session["ir_session"] != null)
        {
            return View("Create", (All_Issues)Session["ir_session"]);
        }

        return View(new All_Issues());
    }
```

FILE UPLOAD

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(Guid? IRID, All_Issues all_Issues)
    {
        Session["ir_session"] = all_Issues;

        HttpFileCollectionBase ir_files;
        List<files_ref> ir_uploadFileModel = new List<files_ref>();

        ir_files = Request.Files;
        string mapPath = "~/App_Data/UploadedFiles/";

        FileUploads ir_fileupload = new FileUploads();
        ir_fileupload.UploadFiles(null, null, IRID, ir_files, mapPath, "IR");

        if (IRID == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = IRID });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting if you ant to display the same data?- you can just use `return View("Create", all_Issues);` although you need to repopulate your SelectLists. But why are you wanting to display the same data again anyway? And nowhere are you saving the data the user has entered so its not clear what your trying to achieve.

Comment: This code works well. It saves the data to the database and upload files as well. The only problem that I encountered is, when I upload files, the text I input on the textboxes and dropdown disappears that is why I still need to retype all over again so that I can save it to the database. The file I uploaded is already there but the text was gone.

Comment: Why are you doing this? (and all your code does is save the file, not any other data as your claiming) Just make one submit and save all the data (from your textboxes and your file input) in one action.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi. Already resolved the problem. I put all the fields in one action just like what you have said and used a MultiAttributeButton class. The data entered in fields are retained even I uploaded a file and it all saves in the database. Thanks for your inputs. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found a solution to this. Just took a long time to post an update.

What I did is still the same. I use session to store the data in my fields and I call this session in every action so that whenever I made a lot of action in the form, the data will retain until the page is submitted.

```
if (Session["ir_session"] != null)
        {
            IMRDTO model = (IMRDTO)Session["ir_session"];
            return View("Create", (IMRDTO)Session["ir_session"]);
        }
```

And with this line of code, which I call in every action, I retain all the data in fields even when the page reloaded.

```
Session["ir_session"] = imr;
```

Hoping it would also help someone.